# Android AppCompat ActionBar MenuItem view customization

Tags: android, view, menu, android-actionbar

Is there a way to change the appearance of action items inflated from *menu.xml* file? If so could you point me to the right direction. Thanks. If you need to know why do I need this, the main reason is that I dislike **the default padding and the default selector**

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured this on my own.

To set custom MenuItem view use ActionProvided. In my case, I just extended ActionProvider class and overrode *onCreateActionView* method. What you'll do more, its up to you :)

Comment: Can You elaborate Your answer With a working code I am also struck with the same problem I need to Remove the Top and Bottom Padding of the MenuItem displayed in the ActionBar